# ActiveMQ: Network connectors created via JMX are not persistent

Tags: activemq-classic

One can create network connectors to exchange messages between two brokers with one of two ways:

1. Edit the `conf/activemq.xml` and adding network connectors inside `<networkConnectors></networkConnectors>`
2. Using the JMX API to add them programmatically via a `BrokerViewMBean`

When creating a network connector via JMX, this is not persistent, i.e. on broker restart it is not there anymore. Is this normal? Is there a way to create NCs using JMX that persist broker restart?

Answer (score 2):

The connections created via JMX are temporary and are not written into the ActiveMQ configuration.  You can view these as devops connections that can be used to test connectivity or to solve some messaging problems but for a permanent solution one needs to edit the ActiveMQ configuration file and add the desired connections there so that on each start they are recreated.